# How to select the specific record from Observable in angular2

Tags: angular, observable

Here is my Role class

```
export class Role {
    id: number;
    name: string;

    constructor(id: number, name: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I have `roles`

```
roles: Observable<Role[]>;
```

and I am filling with

```
this.roles = this.roleService.getAllRoles();
```

Now I want to filter the roles based on `id`. For this, I am using

```
let selectedRole = this.roles.filter(role => role.id === group.role)
                               .map(role=> {console.log(role)});
```

but this is not logging anything :(. Am I missing something? I have just started Angular2

Comment: If that is http then I guess you need to subscribe.

Comment: what does your component look like, could you post it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observable `roles` is a single item that is an array. It's not an observable of the items within that array, so `role.id` does not exist when you are trying to filter. You need to iterate over this array to be able to extract the values:

```
let selectedRole = this.roles.map(arr => 
                      { return arr.filter(role => role.id == group.role) })
```

With this, you end up with an observable `selected` that would be as an Array. Being a bit unsure if you want a single item or several items... but if you need just one item, use `find` instead, then you won't end up with an arraylike observable, but an object like observable.

```
let selectedRole = this.roles.map(arr => 
                      { return arr.find(role => role.id == group.role) })
```

Hope this helps! :)

As to being a bit unclear to as if you want to work with observables or not. In case you do NOT want to work with observables, simply subscribe yourself and then filter the values:

```
this.roleService.getAllRoles()
  .subscribe(data => {
     this.roles = data;
     // create an array with roles that match the group role
     this.selectedRole = this.roles.filter(x => x.id == group.role)
     // find a single role that matches the group.role
     this.selectedRole = this.roles.find(x => x.id == group.role)
  })
```

Comment: Now how cam I print id from selectedRole on console

Comment: now to print values from selectedRole that is of type observable, I have to subscribe selectedRole !! Right ?

Comment: If you are using the latter solution in my answer, you can print the id by `{{(selectedRole | async)?.id}}` If you do not want to work with observables, you need to change the code a bit. But I thought you wanted to work with observables :)

Comment: If you are using the first option you can iterate the observable: `<p *ngFor="let sel of selectedRole | async">{{sel.id}}</p>`

Comment: I updated my answer to use objects instead of observables if that is what you want.